# Invoke transactional method within the same SFSB

Tags: transactions, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, stateful-session-bean

Is it possible to invoke a transactional method from within a Stateful EJB itself? To speak more clearly:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@Stateless
public class MyService {

    @Resource
    SessionContext ctx;

    public void myMethod()  {
        // do something...

        // invoke method from the same class

        // As expected - this doesn't work as it's a regular local-call, 
        // it's not aware of EJB nature of this call.
        save();

        // Doesn't work (although it worked with SLSB)
        ctx.getBusinessObject(MyService.class).save();
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void save() {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is to let the user call myMethod(); I want to be sure that this method is executed without the JTA transaction. After this call I want to invoke a save(); method which will be run within a transaction.

If I use the ctx.getBusinessObject(-) method I get:

> WARNING: A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB
>   MyService method public void com.test.MyService.save()
>   javax.ejb.IllegalLoopbackException: **Illegal Reentrant Access** : Attempt
>   to make a loopback call on method 'public void
>   com.test.MyService.save() for stateful session bean MyService

Are the inner calls not supported for SFSBs?

I'm running Glassfish 3.1.1.

Comment: You can solve this doing the following: Inject the same Service in  your class like this @EJB private MyService self; and then in myMethod() call the save methos like this self.save(). I have tried this in wildfly8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a bug in the Glassfish EJB implementation. It doesn't just happen when you call a method with a different transaction attribute, it happens with every reentrant call to a stateful session bean.

Just try putting a simple test method in your stateful bean and call it via the business object proxy. You'll get the same exception.

On JBoss AS 7, reentrant calls to stateful beans *are* allowed. Incidentally, a similar bug was present in OpenEJB some time ago: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB-1099

Comment: Thanks Arjan. Yeah, I've tested it without different Tx attributes. I will post this on the Glassfish JIRA and see what will happen.

Comment: Do you have an URL to your JIRA entry? I reproduced the issue [here](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/java-ee-concepts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/martinandersson/javaee/ejb/sessionbeans/tests/StatefulTest.java) (see last test method). You may clone this Arquillian test repository and test the project as is really easily. Default Maven profile uses Arquillian's remote adapter for GlassFish, so have that server running. I made this test pass for both WildFly (former JBoss) and GlassFish as I can not declare a winner/looser using the EJB specification only.

Comment: @MartinAndersson In the mean time I've committed a test for this to the [Java EE 7 Samples project](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples. Maybe it's an idea for you to contribute your tests to that project as well? It's more convenient to have all tests in one place (I had a separate suite of JASPIC tests that I contributed as well)

Comment: @PiotrNowicki Did you ever created a GlassFish JIRA for this?

Comment: Arjan, was at first thinking of becoming a contributor but favor my current project setup where everything is just one Maven module with test files and everything is done programmatically. Also, my long term goal is to not just prove or disprove Java EE concepts but also superawesome docs that explain as much as possible with quotes from the specifications.

Comment: Will look into your new test case within a week :) Many thanx to both of you two for your hard community work.